# Expect is skipping some of the output buffer in favor the first re pattern

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

Here's my expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho zsh -li
expect {
  -re {\e]\d+;[^\a]*\a} { send_error "escape found: $expect_out(buffer)\n"; exp_continue }
  "current_dir" { send_error "prompt found: $expect_out(buffer)\n" }
  timeout { exit 1 }
}
```

I'm basically trying to filter out escape sequences that could contain the "current_dir" string, and then match the first time that string appears outside the escape sequences.

The stderr output of running this is:

```
escape found: \e]1337;RemoteHost=me@myhost.local\a
escape found: \e]1337;CurrentDir=/path/to/current_dir\a
escape found: \e]1337;ShellIntegrationVersion=11;shell=zsh\a
escape found: \e[1m\e[7m%\e[27m\e[1m\e[0m \r \r\e]0;current_dir\a
escape found: \e]133;D;0\a
escape found: \e]1337;RemoteHost=me@myhost.local\a
escape found: \e]1337;CurrentDir=/path/to/current_dir\a
escape found: \r\e[0m\e[27m\e[24m\e[J\e]133;A\a
escape found: \r\n\e[1;36m/path/to/current_dir\e[0m on \e[1;35mmaster\e[0m \r\n\e[1;32m%\e[0m \e]133;B\a
```

All the "escape found" matches are valid, unless for the last one. In the 2nd, 4th and 7th matches, we even see that the "current_dir" string is contained inside the sequence, which are the ones that I want to be ignored.

In the last "escape found" output, we see that there was an escape sequence at the end: "\e]133;B\a". But there was a "current_dir" before that which was not matched by the plain "current_dir" match pattern.

I was expecting to see:

```
prompt found: \r\n\e[1;36m/path/to/current_dir
```

instead of the last "escape found" output. But it's timing out instead, as that was passed unnoticed by expect... (notice that the escape sequences I'm trying to ignore start with `\e]` which is different than `\e[`.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: Notice I'm printing the whole `expect_out(buffer)` above. If I changed the rules to only print `expect_out(0,string)`, which is what each rule actually matched, I'd get:

```
escape found: \e]1337;RemoteHost=me@myhost.local\a
escape found: \e]1337;CurrentDir=/path/to/current_dir\a
escape found: \e]1337;ShellIntegrationVersion=11;shell=zsh\a
escape found: \e]0;current_dir\a
escape found: \e]133;D;0\a
escape found: \e]1337;RemoteHost=me@myhost.local\a
escape found: \e]1337;CurrentDir=/path/to/current_dir\a
escape found: \e]133;A\a
escape found: \e]133;B\a
```

so the output I'd like the second rule to match was not matched by the first rule.

Comment: *"so the output I'd like the second rule to match was not matched by the first rule."* -- you are right but this is how Expect works. when it matches `\e]133;B\a`, both the unmatched part (before `\e]133;B\a`) and the matched part (`\e]133;B\a`) are forgotten and will not be tested against other patterns.

Comment: Oh got it. So expect is not trying the rules for each new character of the output buffer, but in chunks (probably looking at the whole buffer just once). Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing that the rules are applied in order, and that subsequent matches happen after the point that the last matched rule matched at. With your problem input buffer, both rules can match, so the first one is matched which consumes everything up to the end, and masks the second one from ever matching.

You need to write your matches somewhat differently so that the rule that picks up what you want is matched before the rule that skips over it. However, that's difficult here because there's a lot of other stuff going on; you probably need a more complex prompt match pattern, and you need to put it *first*.

This *might* work:

```
expect {
    -re {\e\[1;36m([^\e]*)\e\[0m on \e\[1;35m([^\e]*)\e\[0m} {
        send_error "prompt found: $expect_out(buffer)\n"
        send_error "prompt dir: $expect_out(1,string)\n"
        send_error "prompt branch: $expect_out(2,string)\n"
    }
    -re {\e]\d+;[^\a]*\a} {
        send_error "escape found: $expect_out(buffer)\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    timeout {
        exit 1
    }
}
```

---

You might want to consider setting the `TERM` environment variable to `dumb` (disabling almost all of those escapes) before spawning so that you don't have quite so much complexity to deal with. It's also often a good idea to explicitly set the prompt of controlled programs (just for the session) to something that it's easy to match. It's not to say that that's definitely going to work for you here, but those sorts of techniques often help by making the matching problem a lot easier to handle.

You don't really need [iTerm2 escape codes](https://iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html) for this particular application, do you?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I want to have something generic enough, since I won't have full control over the environments configuration, not even how the prompts looks like. And I still want it to be working as an xterm-like terminal, not a dumb one. My fitst rule only matched `$expect_out(1,string)` as `\e]133;B\a`, so I still don't get why the second rule could not pick up the output buffer before that, which is still "after the point that the last matched rule matched at" and even before the point that the last matched matched at...

Comment: The basic problem is that output reaches Expect in lumps, and there's nothing much you can do about that. All expect does is accumulate output, trying matching things each time, until something matches (or timeout or eof is reached). There's a max size of buffer — though I can't remember the details —  but you still have to deal with the fact that if two rules can match a state, the first rule will mask the second.

Comment: Got it. Now that I know expect looks at the output in lumps, all my experiments with this code make sense!

Answer (score 1):

As a reference for anyone with a similar problem -- mainly if you want to be able to ignore iTerm2 escape codes --, any of these two scripts worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho zsh -li
expect {
  -re {\e]133;B\a} { send_error "prompt found: $expect_out(buffer)\n" }
  -re {\e]\d+;[^\a]*\a} { exp_continue }
  "current_dir" { send_error "prompt found: $expect_out(buffer)\n" }
  timeout { exit 1 }
}
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho zsh -li
expect {
  -re {\e]([07]|1337);[^\a]*\a} { exp_continue }
  "current_dir" { send_error "prompt found: $expect_out(buffer)\n" }
  timeout { exit 1 }
}
```

Thanks to @Donald Fellows and @sexpect for making it clear that expect reaches the output buffer in chunks, so we need to be careful with having the rules in the right order for patterns that could occur too close to each other in the output.